# Logo overlay with Windows Movie Maker

Tags: windows-movie-maker

I am currently editing a video with Windows Movie Maker. I am trying to insert an overlay of my logo (which is transparent) on the upper right hand side of my video, but I don't know how to do that. If it is not possible (I heard of some comments saying it's not possible to add a logo in WMM), is there any software which can complete the task?

Comment: I'll leave this open in case someone knows of a way to do it with WMM, however for other options, see https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/tools-to-combine-a-video-with-an-animated-logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with WMM, it doesn't support video compositing.  Filelab Video Editor is a free, online program that can do this for you.